# Prolog error after loading the same file an even number of times?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I am quite new to prolog. I am trying to implement a puzzle solving program, but I am finding this problem and I don't know the cause. When I load the program the first time and execute a query, it will work just fine, if I load again the program, the same query throws the next error:

```
ERROR: Unknown procedure: '__aux_maplist/3_espacos_fila+1'/3
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [12] '__aux_maplist/3_espacos_fila+1'([[...|...],...|...],_31744,h)
ERROR:   [11] espacos_puzzle([[...|...],...|...],_31790) at c:/users/admin/onedrive - universidade de lisboa/documents/github/ist/cadeiras/1ano_2sem/lp/projectos/pacote_projecto/pacote_projecto/projecto1.pl:129
ERROR:    [9] <user>
ERROR:
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
ERROR: Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
   Exception: (12) '__aux_maplist/3_espacos_fila+1'([[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [17, 0], [10, 0]], [[0, 0], [24, 0], [11, 3], 
_29968, _29974], [[0, 16], _30004, _30010, _30016, _30022], [[0, 26], _30052, _30058, _30064|...], [[0, 17], _30100, _30106|...]], _32024, h) ?
```

line 129 is:

```
maplist(espacos_fila(h), Puzzle, Espacos_h_l)
```

and the function espacos_fila/3 receives a constant (h or v (horizontal or vertical)), a line with the format `[[0,17], P52, P53, [0,3], P_55]],` and the third argument is a list of structures of the type `[espaco(17, [P52], [P53]), espaco(3, [P_55])]`.
If I abort and load the program again, I get no errors... I don't understand why do I get the error the second time.
The query is:

```
Puzzle = [[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [17, 0], [10, 0]],
[[0, 0], [24, 0], [11, 3], P24, P25],
[[0,16], P32, P33, P34, P35],
[[0,26], P42, P43, P44, P45],
[[0,17], P52, P53, [0,0], [0,0]]],
espacos_puzzle(Puzzle, Espacos).
```

And the expected result is:

```
Puzzle = [[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [17, 0], [10, 0]], [[0, 0], [24, 0], [11, 3], P24, P25], [[0, 16], P32, P33, P34, P35], [[0, 26], P42, P43, P44, P45], [[0, 17], P52, P53, [...|...]|...]],
Espacos = [espaco(3, [P24, P25]), espaco(16, [P32, P33, P34, P35]), espaco(26, [P42, P43, P44, P45]), espaco(17, [P52, P53]), espaco(24, [P32, P42, P52]), espaco(11, [P33, P43|...]), espaco(17, [P24|...]), espaco(10, [...|...])].
```

(Sorry for not showing much code but it is a project for university, so I can't just copy paste my program on the internet...)

Comment: This may be an error in compilation (i.e. generation of additional predicates by the compiler to handle the maplist/3 call). To wave a dead chicken, try `use_module(library(apply_macros)).` or as a directive `:-use_module(library(apply_macros)).` Which version of SWI-Prolog are you using?

Comment: The version is 8.2.4

Comment: Well, 8.2.4 that's pretty recent.

Comment: This is a known bug: https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/issues/800

Comment: Thank you, I see... But the problem of the workaround is that I am already using :- use_module(library(clpfd)). It is a library that is given as a directive in the common code source file, which I include in my program.

Comment: What if you call `make.` between runs.

Comment: On odd calls, it simply returns true. on even, it returns a bunch of warnings

Comment: Warning: The predicates below are not defined. If these are defined
Warning: at runtime using assert/1, use :- dynamic Name/Arity.
Warning:
Warning: '__aux_maplist/3_espacos_fila+1'/3, which is referenced by
Warning:        (file).pl:132:4: 1-st clause of espacos_puzzle/2
Warning:        (file).pl:135:4: 1-st clause of espacos_puzzle/2
Warning: '__aux_maplist/3_permutacoes_soma_espaco+0'/2, which is referenced by
Warning:        (file).pl:166:4: 2-nd clause of permutacoes_soma_espacos/2
Warning: '__aux_maplist/3_permutation_list+0'/2, which is referenced by

Comment: Warning:        (file).pl:72:4: 1-st clause of permutacoes_soma/4
true.

Comment: However, for now, I do not have any dynamic functors...

Comment: @JavierdeMullerSanta-María If i were you, I would just install a previous version of SWI (one which does not suffer from the bug mentioned)

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will